# Laravel 5.1 PHP DOMDocument() class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using PHP's built-in DOMDocument() class to do some simple web-scraping.
However, it works on my 4.2 site, but not my 5.1 (both are on same installation of PHP).

Here's the error:

> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\III_Ranks\DOMDocument' not found

Here's my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\III_Ranks;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class RanksController extends Controller 
{
    public function getRanks()
    {
        $list1 = new DOMDocument();
        //etc...
    }
}
```

I figure this is a namespace issue, but I have no idea how to access DOMDocument()

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In Laravel 5.1 you must prefix the class name with the global namespace prefix '\'.

So your updated code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\III_Ranks;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class RanksController extends Controller 
{
    public function getRanks()
    {
        $list1 = new \DOMDocument();
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. I also needed to use a slash in front of `DOMXpath` like `$xpath = new \DOMXpath($list1);`

Answer (score 10):

For me, in order to solve the error: `DOMDocument() class not found`. I had to install the [DOM extension](http://www.php.net/en/dom).

**If you are using PHP 5:**

You can do so on Debian / Ubuntu using:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dom
```

And on Centos / Fedora / Red Hat:

```
yum install php-xml
```

**If you are using PHP 7:**

For Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

For CentOS / Fedora / Red Hat:

```
yum install php70w-xml
```

Comment: For Laravel 5.6 use: apt-get install php7.1-xml

Answer (score 5):

Tested in `Laravel 5.4`

you can use keyword `use` :

In top of file before define the class you can write `use DOMDocument;` instead of `new \DOMDocument();`

For eg:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\III_Ranks;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

use DOMDocument;

class RanksController extends Controller {
...
```

what is this '...' ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in **laravel 5.6** on a server with **ubuntu 16.04**, and I solved this issue installing the **xml** package for `php7.1` version, this does not work for me in the `php7.2` version I don't know why.

**1.**- Make sure you have the version 7.1 of php installed, I use this command to select the correct php version in ubuntu:

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
```

**Note:** In case you don't have installed the `php7.1` version, do you need to install it before the above command, in that case you can use this command: `apt-get install php7.1`

**2.**- To install the package XML I was used the following command:

```
apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

**3.**- Restart your apache server, in my case with this command:

```
service apache2 restart
```

I hope to be helpful, this saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Amazon Linux 2 (LAMP) with laravel framework

Please find below steps resolve issues:

```
 sudo systemctl stop httpd 
 sudo yum install  php-xml
 sudo systemctl start httpd
```